# Why is this "Hello, World!" JavaScript code fragment recognized as an acceptable program instruction?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently a coworker showed this fragment of JavaScript code:

```js
greet = "‮".toString.bind("hello world!")
```

If you paste this inside the Developer Console and execute it will print a "Hello, World!" message:

```js
>> console.log(greet())
hello, world!
```

Another interesting thing I found is that if you paste the same `greet` code inside Node.js REPL it will automatically transpile it to a "readable" format.

How does this work? Why is this behaviour possible in a browser and why does Node.js automatically format it?

Comment: Some sort of Unicode reverse bidi characters are involved in that.

Comment: It seems you have there right-to-left override symbol https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202e/index.htm

Comment: You can see the text direction changes even in this page. Try to select the garbled code fragment.

Comment: Also note the syntax-highlighting in the snippet is correct (It doesn't show the `(` as part of the string - interestingly, that character is actually a `)` but the text-direction changes it!)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I guess that actually makes sense - text highlight will go with the order of symbols and not the display order. It's still surprising when you look at it, though.

Comment: And this, dear friends, is why you should be very cautious when copy-pasting code from the Internet into your editor or console ...

Comment: exactly the same, just in Java: [Why does this code, written backwards, print “Hello World!”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43943699/995714)

Comment: @Dubu: And even more cautious [opening e-mail attachments](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2011/09/right-to-left-override-aids-email-attacks/).

Answer (score 177, accepted):

The actual code is:

```
greet = "...".toString.bind("hello world!")
```

Where the `...` in the string literal are the bytes `E2 80 AE`, which is the right-to-left override Unicode character, which causes everything after it to be displayed in reverse. It's used for writing right-to-left languages like Arabic or Hebrew.

[image: hex editors are your friend]

Comment: Do these characters change the way my browser chooses to highlight on double click as well? when I try to double click OP's string it highlights the beginning quote, and end dot and end quote, nothing in between. Interesting.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D yes, they should change selection appropriately in most software that handles RTL text properly.

Comment: The RTL override is _not_ used for writing right-to-left languages. Those automatically render RTL.  The bigger problem is shared characters like numbers.  For those, the renderer has to _guess_ LTR vs RTL based on context.  Developers insert the RTL override character to force the renderer to render neutral direction characters in the desired direction.

Comment: Note that if you need this character for BIDI text and are not deliberately trying to make your JS code look confusing, you'd write it as `\u202e`.

Comment: @Moo It’s used *in the context of writing RTL languages in certain situations.* I didn’t want to go into too much detail as it’s irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Hold on... where is the `...` coming from? I don't see it in OPs code

Comment: @Adelin It's an invisible character. Its only visible effect is the reversal of following characters.

Answer (score 76):

You have hidden characters which reverse the text. Here you can see the raw characters: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php

[image]

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, the basic answer is, this has nothing to do with Javascript whatsoever, and is just Unicode text rendering order, and the choice of using Javascript here is a red herring?

Comment: @JaminGrey apparently so. I suspect you can do the same in a Python or a Ruby REPL or many others. The only JavaScript trick here is the usage of `.bind` to create a bound function out of `toString`. This can easily be substituted with something like `"<reversing unicode>", console.log("hello world")` and you'd still get weird looking but executable code.

Comment: @JaminGrey Presumably, JavaScript was chosen because you can run its source code so easily. (Only needs a normal browser.)

Comment: @JaminGrey I think it's more related to the Developer Console than to Javascript. Ruby and Python consoles simply display `"\u202E"` as an empty character and do not change the direction of the input, so `"hello world!"` is displayed as is, both in the input and output. Depending on your text editor, the script might be written right-to-left for the desired effect. Here's a [Ruby example](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P70oNbVEwVZB165a6VHDutSMnByF/PzynCLFFCW94tIkDX09fR11dU29dDBHQ08TiIAiMUYxhuqatdYFpSXFGmBD9DQ0Nf//BwA).