# Unicode Right To Left Override Character is not working for reversing a string in Java8

Tags: java, string

```
public class ReverseStringUnicodeRightToLeftOverrideCharacter {

    public static String reverse(String str)
        {
            
              return '\u202E' + str;
        }
        public static String reverse(String str)
        {
            //return "\u202D" + str;
              return '\u202E' + str;
        }
public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            
"\u202E" + str  is not working in Java

String str = "Techie Delight";
str = reverse(str);

System.out.println("Reverse of the given string is : " + str); 
            
                  
    }
}
```

For this I'm getting below output:

```
Reverse of the given string is : ?Techie Delight
```

Comment: Refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943699/why-does-this-code-written-backwards-print-hello-world for clearity.

Comment: I already refer this.. I didnt understand what is written there as i m new to java

Answer (score 0):

You have to concatenate it like this:

```
public static String reverse(String str)
    {
        return "\u202E"+str+"\u202D";
    }
```

with "\u202E" as a String not a character at the start and "\u202D" at the end of your string to be reversed.

Comment: The solution which you mentioned is giving me below output:                                      
 Reverse of the given string is : ?Techie Delight?

Comment: public class ReverseString {
  
  public static String reverse(String str)
  {
   //return "\u202D" + str;
     //return '\u202E' + str;
     return "\u202E"+str+"\u202D";
  }

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
   String str = "Techie Delight";
   //byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   //String utf8EncodedString = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   //utf8EncodedString = reverse(utf8EncodedString);
   str = reverse(str);
                       System.out.println("Reverse of the given string is : " + str); 
   }}